# SwiftUI - ForEach does not show changes when filtering <FetchedResults> using an ObservedObject, but does when manually entering

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a CoreData plants entity, a model with a text value, a masterView and a simple detailView

Model:

```
class TextItem: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var text: String = ""
    
    init() {
        id = UUID().uuidString
    }
}


class RecognizedContent: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [TextItem]()
}
```

List in MasterView:

```
        List(recognizedContent.items, id: \.id) { textItem in
          NavigationLink(destination: TextPreviewView(text: textItem.text)
                          .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)) {
            if let item = plants.first(where: {$0.wrappedID == textItem.text}) {
          PlantRow(item: item)
          }
            Text(String(textItem.text))
          }
```

```
struct TextPreviewView: View {
    
var text: String
  
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

  @FetchRequest(
      sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Plant.timestamp, ascending: true)],
      animation: .default)
  private var plants: FetchedResults<Plant>
  
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding()
              
              
              
          ForEach(plants.filter({$0.wrappedID.range(of: String(text), options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}), id: \.self) { plant in
                PlantRow(item: plant)
                Text(plant.visualId ?? "")
            }
          

        }
    }
}
```

plants has a wrappedID (String) with a certain value ("Benjamin" in this case). When I manually replace String(text) in the ForEach filter with "Benjamin" it filters out the correct value and shows the row. Whenever I let text be filled in from the Model, it doesn't find anything. When I, on ButtonClick, cast the text in recognizedContent.items.text to a @State variable and feed that into the filter, it immediately shows the PlantRows.

I've also changed the ForEaches to all possible ways. Whenever I feed in a 'normal' string, the filter works. However, Text(String(textItem.text)) also always renders and shows correct string.

Is it a problem in the ObservedObject?

Comment: try changing `TextItem` to

`struct TextItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var text: String = ""
}`

and there is no need for `String(text)` etc..., `text` is already a string.

Comment: You aren’t observing the individual objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Switfui View when CoreData changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886867/updating-switfui-view-when-coredata-changes)

Comment: I don't think it's the same. The CoreData doesn't change, because when I remove the filter from the ForEach in the detail view, it shows all my objects. When I apply a static test filter, for instance  `ForEach(plants.filter({$0.wrappedName == "Paul"}), id: \.self) { plant in
            PlantRow(item: plant)
          }` it also shows the correct PlantRow. I'd have to observe plants, but the @FetchRequest should take care of that.

Comment: At this point, this needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show compilable code, and upload a screenshot of your Core Data model.