# How do I properly pass an Object in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I encountered a problem regarding View updates. I have some CoreData entities and I want to style my View according to some properties (color, symbol and title - all stored as String).

If I'm populating my List with `CustomCell`'s passing the Entity as a State var:

```
struct CustomCell: View {

@State var liste: ListModel

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        ZStack{
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(ColorCases.getColor(for: liste.color))
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            Image(systemName: liste.icon)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }.padding(.horizontal)
        Text("\(liste.title)")
    }
}
}

struct CustomListView: View {

@State private var lists: [ListModel]

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("All Lists: ")
        List{
            ForEach(lists, id: \.id) { liste in
                ListenListViewRow(liste: liste)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The view is not updating when the value changes, but if I have the code directly included within the list everything works/updates as expected.

What I think is happening is, that the mistake is already in passing the Entity, and that I'm only passing a reference/creating a copy, so I cant see any changes made to the original ? So how do I pass it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Switfui View when CoreData changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886867/updating-switfui-view-when-coredata-changes)

Comment: No, as in my original code the Array is a published Property, in an ObservableObject, this problem is also not only triggered by CoreData, another example would be the new FocusState. works fine if everything is in the same view and breaks as soon as seperated @loremipsum

Comment: `@Published` properties don't observe `ObservableObject`s you have to observe them directly by using `@ObservedObject`

Comment: But if a Published property gets updated, the View updates as well?! @loremipsum

Comment: Not when the variables of a `class` are updated, a `struct` is different. `@State` will change when the item as a whole changes not when the variables are changed. change `@State var liste: ListModel` to `@ObservedObject var liste: ListModel` if the model is an `ObservableObject`/CoreData object  and you will see the changes to the variables.

Comment: Ok, I changed the state var to an ObservedObject var and it works! Thank you @loremipsum